# Firestore snapshot listener data duplication issue in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, pagination, google-cloud-firestore, chat

Hello i am working with fire store database for making one to one chat between user. Here i want some pagination of messages. So i called snapshot listener inside **initState** So the problem is while i navigate to chat screen, **initState**  called snapshot listener **DocumentType.added** automatically. so data becomes duplicate..

here is my code which i called inside **initState**

```
List<DocumentSnapshot> _products = [];
StreamController<List<DocumentSnapshot>> _streamController =
StreamController<List<DocumentSnapshot>>.broadcast();

@override
void initState() {
     db
    .collection('chat')
   .document(docId)
    .collection('messages')
    .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
    .snapshots().listen((data) => onChangeData(
          data.documentChanges,
        ));
}
void onChangeData(
  List<DocumentChange> documentChanges,
) {
  documentChanges.forEach((productChange) {
    if (productChange.type == DocumentChangeType.removed) {
      _products.removeWhere((product) {
        return productChange.document.documentID == product.documentID;
      });

      _streamController.add(_products);
    }
    if (productChange.type == DocumentChangeType.added) {
    _products.insert(productChange.newIndex, productChange.document);
      _streamController.add(_products);
    }
    if (productChange.type == DocumentChangeType.modified) {
      int indexWhere = _products.indexWhere((product) {
        return productChange.document.documentID == product.documentID;
      });

      if (indexWhere >= 0) {
        _products[indexWhere] = productChange.document;
      }

      _streamController.add(_products);   
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: You are passing a List of document changes into the `onChangeData` method. Is this a list you have previously filtered between the data your had locally and the new data coming from `Firestore`?
You mention that this is a 1 to 1 chat, but your variables are `_products` are these the messages?

Comment: `Clear` your list on the top and then `add`

Comment: @João Soares sorry for the bad variable declaration..the products is List<Documentsnapshot>_products

Comment: @BloodLoss can please show me a demo

Comment: @SouravDas Can you please answer my first question. "You are passing a List of document changes into the onChangeData method. Is this a list you have previously filtered between the data your had locally and the new data coming from Firestore?"

Comment: @ João Soares  no i didn't filter any data. I edited my code and add extra details can you please check now.

Comment: Can you share the structure of the Firestore collections/documents where you are storing the messages?

Comment: Are you following the documentation present [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots) to cache already fetched data and get only the changes?

Comment: you can use _streamController.clear() in initState()

Comment: @João Soares yes i am following the dumentation of firebase

Answer (score 1):

This is normal behavior - when you attach a listener to a document or a collection, you first get a callback with the current data, and then subsequent calls whenever the data is changed.

Because you are using pagination, and attaching a new listener within `initState` of each of the pages, you get that first callback on each page change.

What you should do is create a separate class that is responsible for listening to your collection and notifying any widgets that should be updated. You can use the state management library of your choice for notifying the widgets of data changes.

Comment: Frankly, no, because there is no difficulty in what I described above. It's simply time consuming, and I don't have the time. Besides, SO is not for others to write your code, it's so you can find answers to questions that you don't know the answer to. I consider that I have explained very clearly, in plain words, why you are having the problem you are having, and what would fix it.

Comment: Actually I know how to work with state management like Bloc or provider but the problem is onchange listener needs to be called from somewhere and I am confused about it...

Comment: So for example if you use Provider, you would create a class extending ChangeNotifier. This class would attach the Firestore listener, which would in turn call your `onChangeData` function, which in turn updates `_products` and calls `notifyListeners()` when appropriate. You would only have 1 instance of this ChangeNotifier, exposed through Provider. Now each of your pages simply needs to call `Provider.of<YourChangeNotifier>(context)` somewhere in the `build()` method in order to be rebuilt whenever `notifyListeners()` is called.

Comment: so where you called onchange listener from changenotifier class...how to do that

Comment: You move the `onChangeData` function along with `_products` and whatever else you have in there to the ChangeNotifier...

Comment: yes ...but it's a function ..it needs to be trigered by an event..

Comment: ?! Yes, the events are the database changes, that's why you attach a listener to Firestore in the first place. I'm sorry but I can't continue this conversation - it seems that none of my answers are satisfactory, and I'm not sure whether I'm poor at answering or whether you're poor at questioning. I give up.